# How to find the nearest 100 meters latitude and longitude depending upon the current location in android

Tags: android

How to find the nearest 1000 meters latitude and longitude depending upon the current location in android to get nearest place from sql lit database

Comment: use hypersine formula to calculate distance between 2 location

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are using the on-phone database to store all your locations. Its safer to use the server side.
Assuming that you have the latitude and longitude saved in your database table, the modification is needed only in the query. The following is an SQL query that solved my problem:

```
"SELECT * FROM places WHERE (acos(sin(places.lat * 0.0175) * sin($userLat * 0.0175) + cos(places.lat * 0.0175) * cos($userLat * 0.0175) * cos(($userLon * 0.0175) - (places.lon * 0.0175))) * 3959 <= $locateRadius)"
//userLat and userLon refer to your current location
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean when you say "sql lite database" as the current location should not be stored in any database on the phone, unless you explicitly store it there in a different app.

This should be in your main activity:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationlistener = new mylocationlistener();
locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationlistener);
```

...

```
private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            Log.d("latitude", location.getLatitude());
            Log.d("longitude", location.getLongitude());                
        }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I guess your question is more about algorithm, right?

This document describes the data structure and algorithms for geometric approximation, might be helpful to you.

https://www.box.com/s/7lomb99vsmjsh77ud4eh